# Why would a MySQL DELETE statement fail when the corresponding SELECT statement works?

Tags: python, mysql, google-cloud-platform, pymysql

I have a MySQL database instance hosted on GCP, and I am connecting to it using the [pymysql](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/) python package. I would like to delete some rows from a database table called **Basic**.

The code I have written to do this is included below. The variable **conf** contains the connection details to the database instance.

```
import pymysql
import pandas as pd

# Establish connection.
connection = pymysql.connect(**conf)
cursor = connection.cursor()

# Delete rows of table.
try:
    cursor.execute("DELETE FROM Basic WHERE Date = '2022-11-25 04:00:00';")

except Exception as ex:
    print("Exception occured: %s" %ex) 

finally:
    connection.close()

# Check the table to see if deletion has occurred.
connection = pymysql.connect(**conf)
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Basic WHERE Date = '2022-11-25 04:00:00'")
connection.close()

df = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(), columns = ["Date", "State", "Price", "Demand"])
```

Clearly one would expect the dataframe defined here to have no rows, but this is not the case. This shows that the SELECT statement included in the code above produces the expected result, but the corresponding DELETE statement does not.

Why is this the case?

Comment: from what you've provided, the only blemish in code i see is in,    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Basic WHERE Date = '2022-11-25 04:00:00';") <--- is missing semicolon, depending on the DB engine, this may be an issue.  After the DELETE, have you logged on to the google panel to verify that the rows where delete?

Comment: Did you get an exception?

Comment: You didn't commit the delete.

Comment: Thanks @JohnGordon. This resolves the issue. I'll post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above requires the addition of the following line, in order to commit the DELETE statement.

```
connection.commit()
```

The commit method should be called after every transaction that modifies data, such as this one.